# R data.table merge produces inconsistent results (or I am missing something)

Tags: r, merge, data.table

```
a <- statuses[ID %between% c(59098, 59102), -c('Date')]
b <- restrictions[ID %between% c(59098, 59102), -c('Class', 'Date')]
c <- merge(a, b, by=c('Period', 'ID', 'MedID'), all.x=TRUE, allow.cartesian = TRUE)

d <- merge(statuses[ID %between% c(59098, 59102), -c('Date')], 
restrictions[ID %between% c(59098, 59102), -c('Class', 'Date')], 
by=c('Period', 'ID', 'MedID'), all.X=TRUE, allow.cartesian = TRUE)
```

a has 4 rows and b 5. c has 7 rows (correct) but d has only 5.

Given that c and d are basically doing the same merge, shouldn't they have the same number of rows?

Comment: You're going to need to provide reproducible data that shows the problem. Otherwise we're all guessing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, you have a typo - `all.X=TRUE` instead of `all.x=TRUE`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all.X=TRUE is wrong so it's not taking all from that side
Change it to

```
d <- merge(statuses[ID %between% c(59098, 59102), -c('Date')], 
restrictions[ID %between% c(59098, 59102), -c('Class', 'Date')], 
by=c('Period', 'ID', 'MedID'), all.x=TRUE, allow.cartesian = TRUE
```

Explains why d has same rows as B.

Comment: Thank you! I spent an hour on this - may be time to check my eyesight :-)